# When using Exposed's method "createMissingTablesAndColumns", I get a NoSuchElementException

Tags: kotlin-exposed

I'm using 0.22.1 Exposed libs (core/dao/jdbc) and when I use "SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns", my tables are created but I get an Exception.

If I relaunch the server with a new column, I get the same Exception and the update isn't performed

See the stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseMetadataImpl$tableConstraints$$inlined$associateWith$lambda$1.invoke(JdbcDatabaseMetadataImpl.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseMetadataImpl$tableConstraints$$inlined$associateWith$lambda$1.invoke(JdbcDatabaseMetadataImpl.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseMetadataImplKt.iterate(JdbcDatabaseMetadataImpl.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseMetadataImpl.tableConstraints(JdbcDatabaseMetadataImpl.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.VendorDialect$fillConstraintCacheForTables$1.invoke(Default.kt:639)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.VendorDialect$fillConstraintCacheForTables$1.invoke(Default.kt:560)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.jdbc.JdbcConnectionImpl.metadata(JdbcConnectionImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database.metadata$exposed_core(Database.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.VendorDialect.fillConstraintCacheForTables(Default.kt:639)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.VendorDialect.columnConstraints(Default.kt:617)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils.addMissingColumnsStatements(SchemaUtils.kt:145)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns(SchemaUtils.kt:241)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns$default(SchemaUtils.kt:229)
    at repository.database.DatabaseRepository$createTableAndColumn$1.invoke(DatabaseRepository.kt:36)
    at repository.database.DatabaseRepository$createTableAndColumn$1.invoke(DatabaseRepository.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$inTopLevelTransaction$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:156)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$inTopLevelTransaction$2.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:197)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:196)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$transaction$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:134)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction$default(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:103)
    at repository.database.DatabaseRepository.createTableAndColumn(DatabaseRepository.kt:35)
    at repository.database.DatabaseRepository.createAndUpdateDB(DatabaseRepository.kt:31)
    at domain.database.PrepareDatabaseUseCase.performNow(PrepareDatabaseUseCase.kt:18)
    at controller.MainController.<init>(MainController.kt:18)
    at controller.MainControllerKt.main(MainController.kt:10)
```

My tables are simple (just for test) :

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.IntIdTable

object UserTable: IntIdTable()
```

and

```
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.IntIdTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Column

object SpaceTable: IntIdTable() {
    val userIdColumn: Column<EntityID<Int>> = reference("userId", UserTable.id)
}
```

When I try the method "SchemaUtils.create", everything is ok but, of course, when I relaunch the server with some news columns, columns aren't created

Have you an idea to how fix this ? What I doing wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: I try to simplify again for the same result : ```object SpaceTable: IntIdTable() {
    val user = reference("user", UserTable)
}```

From the documentation : https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/exposed/

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I use postgresql 11

Comment: Do you need some more informatios @Tapac ? I'm really blocked :(. I don't have the problem with an other project using exposed 0.16

Comment: One more thing could you please check the same code with 0.21.1 version?

Comment: Well done, its works with 0.21.1 and same code. Do you want more informations to reproduce, debug and fix the problem ? (I can move on ! youhou !)

Comment: Sure, you will help very much if you could share a sample code/project where you got the exception. Share it here or create an issue at https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/

Comment: Tonight (French time), I'll try to provide you a sample project with the exception ;)